# Multiple X-UA-Compatible meta tags on one page

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, meta, x-ua-compatible

What happens if you have multiple X-UA-Compatible meta tags on one page?

For example:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

I wasn't able to find any solid documentation or SO answers for this question - however, after running some of my own tests on Internet Exploder it seems that the browser simply ignores the second meta tag. Is anyone able to corroborate/refute this?

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be valid when running this in the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea). There is a complete answer I would recommend if you'd like to learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/3175642).